# failed to push to laravel repository premission denied

Tags: git

i am trying to contribute to laravel . I wrote some code and created a new branch and when i try to push the code on git i get this error :

[image]

i cloned the repo with ssh and I am pretty sure that i can push and pull from git , i also tried to update my git credentials but again no luck with it  . any idea what can be wrong here ?

detail of console :

```
15:26:48.303: [framework] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false checkout -b feat/add-first-or-fail-to-query-builder HEAD --
Switched to a new branch 'feat/add-first-or-fail-to-query-builder'
M   src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
15:28:35.310: [framework] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
15:28:35.472: [framework] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false commit -F C:\Users\farsh\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt --
[feat/add-first-or-fail-to-query-builder 18d0b9917a] add the firstOrFail function to the query builder
 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+)
15:28:42.758: [framework] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/feat/add-first-or-fail-to-query-builder:refs/heads/feat/add-first-or-fail-to-query-builder --set-upstream
ERROR: Permission to laravel/framework.git denied to farshadff.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the "details in the console" the error message mentions? I would guess you tried pushing to the upstream repo, not your fork.

Comment: @SebDieBln yes just added

Comment: 1 more point is that i can pull from the repo and have no problem on pulling

Comment: It looks like `farshadff` has permission to *read* this `laravel/framework.git` repository, but not to *write* to it. Check the permissions settings on whatever hosting system you're using. Note that *Git* lacks this kind of permission control, so it's not Git doing any of this, it's entirely up to whatever software exists on the hosting system.

Comment: @Farshad Can you please run `git remote -v` and show the output of that? This let's us understand where you want to push to, i.e. where your `origin` remote is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you cannot directly push to a public repository used by many users: there often is a *limited* list of contributors, who can contribute to the repository.

You should **[fork the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)** first, change your local origin URL to that fork, and push to it (which you will be able to do, since you would be the *owner* of the new repository.

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/framework.git
```

From there, make a [pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) between your branch and `laravel/framework.git` `main` branch.